# (hello-> h3o) How to replace in a String the middle letters for the number of letters replaced

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to build a method which receive a String e.g. "elephant-rides are really fun!". and return another similar String, in this example the return should be: "e6t-r3s are r4y fun!". (because e-lephan-t has 6 middle letters, r-ide-s has 3 middle letters and so on)

To get that return I need to replace in each word the middle letters for the number of letters replaced leaving without changes everything which isn't a letter and the first and the last letter of every word.

for the moment I've tried using regex to split the received string into words, and saving these words in an array of strings also I have another array of int in which I save the number of middle letters, but I don't know how to join both arrays and the symbols into a correct String to return

```
String string="elephant-rides are really fun!";
String[] parts = string.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
int[] sizes = new int[parts.length];
int index=0;

for(String aux: parts)
{    
    sizes[index]= aux.length()-2;
    System.out.println( sizes[index]);
    index++;     
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just split by spaces and dashes and take the words length -2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String text = "elephant-rides are really fun!";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(?U)(\\w)(\\w{2,})(\\w)");
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1) + m.group(2).length() + m.group(3));
}
m.appendTail(sb); // append the rest of the contents
System.out.println(sb);
// => e6t-r3s are r4y fun!
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/mRmiX7)

Here, `(?U)(\\w)(\\w{2,})(\\w)` matches any Unicode word char capturing it into Group 1, then captures any 2 or more word chars into Group 2 and then captures a single word char into Group 3, and inside the `.appendReplacement` method, the second group contents are "converted" into its length.

[Java 9+](http://ideone.com/4C0ZHD):

```
String text = "elephant-rides are really fun!";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(?U)(\\w)(\\w{2,})(\\w)");
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
String result = m.replaceAll(x -> x.group(1) + x.group(2).length() + x.group(3));
System.out.println( result );
// => e6t-r3s are r4y fun!
```

Answer (score 0):

For the instructions you gave us, this would be sufficient:

```
String [] result = string.split("[\\s-]");
for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    result[i] = "" + result[i].charAt(0) + ((result[i].length())-2) + result[i].charAt(result[i].length()-1);
}
```

With your input, it creates the array `[ "e6t", "r3s", "a1e", "r4y", "f2!" ]`

And it works even with one or two sized words, but it gives result such as:

Input: *`I am a small`*; Output: `[ "I-1I", "a0m", "a-1a", "s3l" ]`

Again, for the instructions you gave us this would be legal.

Hope I helped!